# Fail installing NVR CMS program, windows 10

Tags: windows

I have a Besder NVR, for 3 years now which works perfectly including CMS program to display NVR contents.
After re-Installing Windows 10 again, I tried to re-install its CMS software, but I get an error after CMS's successful installation:

[image: this]

As said, same software was installed and executed as needed before reinstalling, but now - I get an error.

Tries:

1. After contacting the seller, he sent again an [installation](http://ks3-cn-beijing.ksyun.com/xmcfs-new/jsUploadTest/2019-03-13/General_Bate_CMS_V3.1.0.9.T.20190306.exe?spm=a2g0s.imconversation.0.0.2dcd3e5fB3ZmvY&file=General_Bate_CMS_V3.1.0.9.T.20190306.exe) file, which ended with same result.
2. Compatibility - tried to run as `Supervisor` and any past windows versions available, but still, same error.

What else can be done ?

Comment: We might be able to guess our way to a solution, but your seller should really provide a working set of files.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a dependency issue. I would suggest installing the latest Microsoft C++ Redistributable and the latest .Net Framework runtime.

C++ Runtime - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0

.Net Framework - https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework

Comment: C++ was installed. .NET wasn't need ( said it is already up to date ). BUT, still same error

Comment: Okay, then I would reach out to the vendor to see if there are any other pre-requisites.

Comment: Asked... but still it is an Ali Express seller, they are not IT. And it worked earlier on same OS

Comment: "And it worked earlier on same OS" is irrelevant. What else was installed on the other machine?

Comment: also tried older versions of C++, without any change